# Using jq, how to determine the maximum depth of a JSON document if it cannot be loaded into memory?

Tags: json, nested, jq, depth

The downloadable binaries for the C implementation of [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) come with a rather low hard-coded value of MAX_PARSING_DEPTH (currently 256).

Without having to recompile jq, what are my options for determining the depth of nesting of a JSON document at the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

The streaming parser that comes with jq does not seem to impose any particular limit and can be used as follows:

```
jq --stream -n '[inputs[0]|length]|max' input.json
```

or more economically using the same invocation but with the program:

```
def max(s): reduce s as $_ (null; if $_ > . then $_ else . end);
max(inputs[0]|length)
```

Another option might be to use the Go implementation, which has a limit that lies somewhere between 1024 and 10000.  This is the invocation I've used:

```
    gojq 'def max(s): reduce s as $_ (null; if $_ > . then $_ else . end);
  max(paths|length)' input.json
```